# Django latex template with images

Tags: python, django, pdf, django-templates, latex

I'm trying to generate pdf from django latex template. To do so I'm using the code from [here](https://blog.rumpelsepp.de/2014/09/23/generating-pdfs-with-django-and-latex.html):

So I have this code in **views.py**

```
context = {....}
template = get_template('my_latex_template.tex')
rendered_tpl = template.render(context).encode('utf-8')
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:  
    for ppp in range(2):
        process = Popen(
            ['pdflatex', '-output-directory', tempdir],
            stdin=PIPE,
            stdout=PIPE,
            stderr=PIPE,
        )
        process.communicate(rendered_tpl)
    with open(os.path.join(tempdir, 'texput.pdf'), 'rb') as f:
        pdf = f.read()
r = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')  
r.write(pdf)
```

Here is **my_latex_template.tex**

```
{% autoescape on %}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
 blabla
\includegraphics{img.png}
\end{document}
{% endautoescape %}
```

The structure of my directories:

```
myapp
|..templates
|..|..my_latex_template.tex
|..|..img.png
|..views.py
...
```

When compiling this latex template without \includegraphics{img.png}, everything works perfect.
When compiling it with the image, I'm getting error that

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/73/r8hl47ld11l68v_1kjh_m61m0000gn/T/tmprfp7wf_x/texput.pdf'

That basically means that this temporary file is not generating correctly by running pdflatex on rendered template...

---

Interesting that when I'm doing following in **my_latex_template.tex**

```
{% autoescape on %}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
blabla
{% endautoescape %}
\includegraphics{img.png}
{% autoescape on %}
\end{document}
{% endautoescape %}
```

The code compiles correctly and I'm getting pdf, but instead of image [I'm getting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZdkd.png) -- picture doesn't show correctly

---

Do you have any ideas on what can I do? I would be super grateful if someone could help me.

Thank you

Comment: have you tried `\includegraphics{ {% static 'path/to/img.png'%} }`?